# Can PhpStorm dump a MySQL database into a sql file?

Tags: database, mysql, phpstorm

I know PhpStorm can connect to a database and work with it. Is it possible to export the database to a myDb.sql file with phpstorm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can export data from tables. Some types of database allows you to `Copy DDL` of any node.

More at

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/10/database-tools-and-sql-editor-changes-in-phpstorm-7/ section **Exporting Data**
- http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/database-tool-window.html

Comment: You can easily see table/index definitions as well (`Copy DDL` action).

Comment: @LazyOne True enough, updated the answer, I usually use it with SQLite and there is no such option.

Answer (score 11):

As of this writing (2018.1), right clicking on a database gives you the option to "Dump with 'mysqldump'".

Comment: And this will dump everything to a single file, which makes everything much easier. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it but for some reason it asked for me mysql user password (I don't have any password for my local environment) upon submitting with empty field nothing happens.

Answer (score 8):

No, in phpstorm there is no such option.

You only can export *single Tables* from the Database by clicking on ONE single Table (doesn't work if you mark more than one Table) and open Mouse-Menu (right mouseclick). There you choose "Save to File..." an Choose what you need (for example " SQL Insert Statements".

For having a good DB-Client to manage the whole Stuff, use DBeaver (Standalone Version), or MysqlWorkbench.
I preffer DBeaver.

Comment: FYI, you can right click on the database and dump to file. still individual export files, but dont have to select one by one.

Comment: @jwoodward : You are right, current Versions have this now.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest editions you can right click on a Database and dump to file. It exports to individual files per table.

Answer (score 0):

As of **phpstorm 2019.2.5** you can

**right-click your database/schema > Dump To FIle(s) > SQL Inserts**

to export you DB Structure and Data, see below image for ref.

[image: screenshot of toolbar]